# The difference between passive simple & passive perfect simple

Tags: passive-voice

I learn english and I have one question about passive voices. The next sentence is difficult for me:

"The decision is made".

I've search it in the context translations and have found various translations. Some of them are like "[somebody] has made the decision" (present perfect), but some of them are like "[somebody] generally makes the decision" (present simple). The first means that the act of making the decision is finished. But the second means that somebody sometimes makes the decision at all.

And I don't understant what is correct? Can I use "the decision is made" as "the decision has been made"? Or it'll be a mistake? Is it a universal form which anyone can understand like he wants to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different meanings for *the decision is made*.

One of them is the passive of the simple present *somebody makes the decision*, and like the simple present generally, would only be used in a timeless or habitual sense, for example.

> When a question arises in committee, there is a procedure to be followed ... Then the decision is made, and the committee can move on to the next item.

The other meaning is not a true passive, but a copular sentence with the **adjective** *made*. This construction is not available for all verbs: generally only for verbs which describe changing something, eg "made", "gone", "finished", "closed", but not for example "seen", or "read" or "wanted".